# Solving heat equation for insulated copper rod

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> A copper rod 50 cm long with insulated lateral surface has initial temperature $u(x,0)=2x$, and a time $t=0$ its two ends are insulated. a.) Find $u(x,t)$. b.) What will its temperature be at $x=10$ after 1 min? c.) After approximately how long will its temperature at $x=10$ be 45 degrees celsius?

Here, $k=1.15 \frac{cm^2}{s}$ (according to my textbook). $L=50cm$, $u_x(0,t)=u_x(50,t)=0$. $f(x)=u(x,0)=2x$

$$a_0=\frac{2}{50}\int_0^{50}2xdx=100$$
$$a_n=\frac{2}{50}\int_0^{50}2xcos(\frac{n\pi x}{50})dx= 200\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{\pi^2n^2}$$

Finding $u(x,t)$ I get $$u(x,t)=50+\Sigma \hspace{1mm} 200\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{\pi^2n^2}e^{\frac{-1.15n^2\pi^2t}{50^2}}\cos(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{50^2}x)$$ where $n=1,2,3...$

Whenever I estimate b.), I get a number that is different from their answer. $u(10,60) \approx 19.159$, and the book gives the answer as $25.15$. Similarly for c.), the book gives the answer as 6 mins 54.3 seconds, whereas my answer yielded 7.68 minutes.

Am I simply miscalculating or am I misunderstanding some aspect of the problem? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I should also mention that I am estimating the series with $n=1$.

Comment: did you get the solution of $u$ by solving some heat/diffusion equation $u_t = ku_{xx}$? If so, since you are asking for a checking why don't you show your steps?

Comment: Yes, $u_t=ku_{xx}$. I was curious if my formula for $u(x,t)$ was incorrect, but I can add steps shortly as well.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm having some doubts when substituting in $t=0$ to match your initial conditions. But perhaps you are correct

Comment: $$\cos(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{50^2}x) \longrightarrow \cos(\frac{n\pi}{50}x)$$

Comment: @WW1 thank you, I forgot to take the square root!